# PlayN, Android version of a new project gives an error

Tags: android, html, playn

I've been following the beginner PlayN tutorial at http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/BeginnerInstallationGuide

So basically I've downloaded PlayN sources, setup a new Maven project. 
Then, the Desktop Java version runs as described. With the Android version, I get this error: E/AndroidRuntime?(370): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1180)

I left the generated sources as is, any clues?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exact command you are running and  indicate where you are seeing this particular error message? Also, are you deploying to the simulator or a device?

Comment: Hi samskivert, I am using Run As > Adroid application, using simulator Level 10 API. The error message appears in Logcat.

Comment: EDIT: the first error in the chain is
E/AndroidRuntime(370): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing Android via Eclipse is not currently working. If you want to test a PlayN game in Eclipse, you need to do it via the command line, like so:

```
cd mygame
mvn clean package
cd android
mvn android:deploy
```

Also, I don't believe that you can currently test using the emulator due to lacking or limited support of OpenGL in the emulator. So you'll need to test on a real device.

Comment: I got it working with a real device, however not before going to mygame/pom.xml and commenting out <module>flash</module> section - this was giving me errors before (and I do have Flash Builder 4.5 installed). those errors prevented the android compilation. I also specified ANDROID_HOME env var.
What's still puzzling me is:
how i am going to play sounds with PlayN, without using Flash?

Comment: The flash module in the generated projects is for a completely Flash-based version of your game, not one that is mostly HTML5 but only uses Flash for audio. That's the html module. The flash backend in PlayN is currently broken, and has been disabled in the latest version of the Maven archetype.